# jquery ajax data shows [object Object]

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a very basic ajax call to alert the data that was reported from the server

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/someform/act", //edit utl to url
       data: { changed: JSON.stringify(plainData) }, //edit to include
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);             //data not $data
       },
       error: function() {
          //error condition code
       }
});
```

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the jquery website regarding data field on the success callback, it says that data returned is the data from the server. However for some strange reason when I alert `$data`, I get `[object Object]`

I was expecting to see something like this, since that is what the server would send back

```
<status>0</status>
```

EDIT:

data is also passed along as the POST

Comment: What do you get if you use `alert(data);`?

Comment: The server sent back XML, jQuery then parsed said xml. What you have is an xml document. Try `console.log(data)`

Comment: I get `success` when I alert data

Comment: Then your server isn't returning what you think it is, or, the problem is with something that isn't included in your code above.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that was cause however I have modified the code above to reflect my code

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`alert()` prints the string representation of the arguments - hence if you pass an object, you'll get `[object Object]`.

To inspect data, use `console.log(data)` better.

Answer (score 50):

You need to use `JSON.stringify(data)` in the `alert` to get anything readable.

Also, `$data` is a completely different variable name than `data`.

Comment: Not really, it depends on what `data` is. Maybe it is already a string.

Comment: I get `success` back as a response. I was hoping to get the xml back from the server

Comment: I get `{"0":{},"length":1}`

Answer (score 8):

If you server send a JSON, you need to put `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call. Be aware there's some mistake in your ajax call.

```
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/someform/act", // NOT 'UTL',
               data: {
                  key: value,
                  key2: value2
               },
               // or data: plaindata, // If 'plaindata' is an object.
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data); // As moonwave99 said
               },
               error: function() {
                  //error condition code
               }
        });
```

**EDIT**

When sending data, you should send an object. jQuery will handle the array to sned it to the server. So if plain data is an object, it should be like this

```
               data: plainData,
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending data via `$.ajax({...})`, the Network tab of your browser inspector might be showing `[object Object]` in the `Payload` (Chrome) / `Request` (Firefox) sub-tab, like in the following image (Firefox):

[image]

The reason for this might be in the way you're forming your AJAX call. Specifically:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/example-endpoint',
  data: {'fooKey':fooData,'barKey':barData},
  type: 'post',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false, // this one will turn your data into something like fooKey=fooData&barKey=barData
  processData: false, // and this one will make it [object Object]:""
  beforeSend: function() {
    // whatever it is you need to do
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // do stuff
  },
  error: function(desc, err) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

When combined, `contentType: false` and `processData: false` turn your data into `[object Object]`, because you're actually telling your AJAX call to ignore the content type of whatever is being sent, and not to process it.