# Server-side table deletes row from tables (but not database) using JS, Php, or Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

Project Link: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/

This following code correctly deletes a row in a table:

```
  $('#example').on('click', '.delete_btn', function () {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var data = table.row( row ).data().delete;
      console.log(data);
      alert("delete_btn clicked");
      row.remove();
    });
```

However, it is not permately deleting the row. If you refresh the page, the row that got 'deleted' still exists. I believe this is because I am not deleting the row out of the database. Normally in php you safely remove a row in a database with something like this:

```
id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['del']);
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
header('location: index.php');
```

**EDIT: Revised Code Index.php:**

```
  (document).ready(function() {
var asc = true;
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
"url": "server.php",
"type": "POST",
},

//http://live.datatables.net/xijecupo/1/edit
columnDefs: [{
targets: -1,
defaultContent: '<button type="button" class="delete_btn">Delete</button>'
}],
rowGroup: {
dataSrc: 1
}
});

$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_btn',function(){

        var del_id= $(this).closest('tr');
        var ele = $(this).parent().parent();  //removed the "$" from the ele variable. It's a js variable.
        console.log(del_id);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            dataType: 'json', //This says I'm expecting a response that is json encoded.
            data: { 'del_id' : del_id}, 

            success: function(data){ //data is an json encoded array.

              console.log('Data: ' + data); //Going to display whats in data so you can see whats going on.

              if(data['success']){  //You are checking for true/false not yes or no.
                console.log('You successfully deleted the row.');
                alert("delete btn clicked");
                ele.remove();
              }else{
                console.log('The row was not deleted.');
                }

             }

            });
        });
}); //http://jsfiddle.net/zfohLL0a/

}); //end doc ready
```

**delete.php code:**

```
$del_id = $_POST['del_id']; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?"); //LIMIT 1
$stmt->bind_param('i', $del_id);
$confirmDelete = $stmt->execute();

$array['success'] = FALSE; //Initialize the success parameter as false.
if($confirmDelete){ //Check to see if there was an affected row.
  $array['success'] = TRUE;
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**Partial Solution:**  [Sample format how to setup the ajax.](https://github.com/sokchab/phpserverside/blob/master/index.html)  You have to start off by using the datatables.net "ajax": method for the original server.php. But then after that you use the normal $.ajax methods for the add.php, delete.php, etc. It is confusing because you use two different syntax for ajax. Easiest to just look at the sample link.  [Youtube video for same code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-mc-yMSy2Y&t=614s)

Another helpful link that discusses sending info to and from the ajax/json are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062951/jquery-ajax-data-shows-object-object)    [two](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617157/removing-rows-from-datatables-from-a-ajax-call?rq=1)   [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724383/delete-row-with-ajax-function-and-php)

Comment: You need to send data to server with ajax to let it know to remove from database. Server has no idea you remove something from inside the browser only. Studying some ajax tutorials should help

Comment: Ok. I will. While you are online... I am assuming the end result will look something along the lines like this?    $.ajax({
            url: 'remove.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id:deleteid },
            success: function(response){

                // Removing row from HTML Table
                $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){      
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });

Comment: yes except you are showing using `$_GET['del']` which doesn't match your method or object key for the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer using your latest updated code.**

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_btn',function(){

        var del_id= $(this).closest('tr');
        var ele = $(this).parent().parent();  //removed the "$" from the ele variable. It's a js variable.
        console.log(del_id);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            dataType: 'json', //This says I'm expecting a response that is json encoded.
            data: {  //Set up your post data as an array of key value pairs.

              'del_id' : del_id

            }, 

            success: function(data){ //data is an json encoded array.

              console.log('Data: ' + data); //Going to display whats in data so you can see whats going on.

              if(data['success']){  //You are checking for true/false not yes or no.
                console.log('You successfully deleted the row.');
                ele.fadeOut().remove();
              }else{
                console.log('The row was not deleted.');
                }

             }

            });
        });
});
```

**delete.php**

```
$del_id = $_POST['del_id']; 
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?"); //LIMIT 1
$stmt->bind_param('i', $del_id);
$confirmDelete = $stmt->execute();

$array['success'] = FALSE; //Initialize the success parameter as false.
if($confirmDelete){ //Check to see if there was an affected row.
  $array['success'] = TRUE;
}

echo json_encode($array); //Your ajax is setup to expect a json response.  
//json_encode the $array and echo it out.  You have to do this.  
//When you "echo" out a value, that is what the server is going to submit back to the ajax function.
//If you do not do this, the ajax script will not recieve a response from the delete.php page.
```

This code should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for info. Will carefully read your post and this youtube video. And will try out your code. May have a question in a day or so. Thanks.

Comment: Hey no problem..  There is a ton of info out there on jquery/ajax.  I find it is best just to get a simple ajax request to work, then add the stuff you need it to later.  Anyways Cheers!

Comment: silly question... here is my ajax code (that currently works).  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
"url": "server.php",
"type": "POST",
},      What is the difference between "ajax":   versus $.ajax({

Comment: This ajax format uses "ajax": https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html    not  $.ajax({

Comment: The difference is that you are using some sort of class named dataTable.  The dataTable has an ajax "method" built into it.  You are telling the dataTable class to "use" ajax.  And in the ajax method you supplied a url and the type.  $.ajax would be if you were to write your own ajax properties for your own custom function outside of the dataTable class.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok. That is sort of what I figured. Because I am realizing that datatables.net seems to have a slightly different synatax format.  So I may have to make some minor adjustments but the general theory is all there still.

Comment: Yes its the same code really.  But the dataTable class has done the work for you.

Comment: so i will have to use datatables format. something like "ajax": remove.php.... then later "ajax": add.php.   I am assuming.

Comment: You would substitute the url's.. Leave post the same.  There may be more parameters like the data that you have to pass, I don't know. But your PHP side variables have to match whatever variables the dataTable class is sending it.  Just read the docs.  If this is your first ajax experience just keep tinkering away.  You will learn alot.  Once you get the general idea all the others will be easier.

Comment: Ok. This is a sample formate for any future readers 
 (and for myself so I do not lose it) https://github.com/sokchab/phpserverside/blob/master/index.html    It starts off with using the origina datatables "ajax": for the server.php..... but then later on it transitions into uses the normal format of $.ajax

Comment: i just updated my current code. I am pretty sure it is 99.9% right. I just cant find the syntax error? It 'works' but says "cannot delete row".

Comment: @Scott Schmidt - Please check updated code.  Copy and paste it over.

Comment: i agree with your code updates. however, the website surprisingly freezes now when you click the delete button. here is a sample test page where it freezes: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/test.php    . This makes it hard to debug because i cannot get to the console where 'data' and 'del_id' is logged. been looking into any synatax errors...

Comment: ...maybe this error is indirectly causing the delete button to not work: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT ,' at line 1You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT ,' at line 1"                                                                                                                      ....... looking into this syntax error now.

Comment: That is certainly an error you would get from an sql problem.  This is in the interest of trouble shooting the problem in the most efficient way possible.  Have you just pasted my code in as I have it written with nothing else added to it just so you can get a working ajax query.  Once you know your ajax is working then you can add to it in small steps.  Then when you start having issues you know the issue arose after you lasted added something.  If you  just add a bunch of code trouble shooting can be time consuming and non-productive.  Get something small working and expand. Cheers

Comment: continued....Also, please update your question with your most current code.  It makes it hard to help if I post code, then you make changes, and say something no working right and I look in your question and can't find anything that would make an error that you are describing.  Thank you.

Comment: ok. new code posted. i did an exact copy paste after redoing it myself. i am reading many articles on the limit post error. i do not think it effects the delete but i should figure out what it is...

Comment: just take the limit out.  If your id's are unique then only 1 should ever be deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178901/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-scott-schmidt).

Comment: someone suggested this: "The main stack problem is caused by var edit_id = $(this).closest('tr'); . You try to send that whole jQuery object as data in the ajax. Then jQuery can't serialize it internally and throws a fit

You probably want some property like ID or a data attribute from that row to send (not clear what expectations are)"

Comment: and yeah sorry i was on my ipad and fell asleep while reading our convo it was like 4am.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Joesph's response who was extremely helpful:

"The console shows "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". It looks as though the Ajax call isn't being issued (nothing is showing on the network tab) - so it must be when creating the request. I suspect I may need to JSON.stringify your del_id."

Someone suggested this:
"The main stack problem is caused by var edit_id = $(this).closest('tr'); . You try to send that whole jQuery object as data in the ajax. Then jQuery can't serialize it internally and throws a fit

You probably want some property like ID or a data attribute from that row to send (not clear what expectations are)."

Please post if you have any recommendations. I will edit in any finalized code solution soon.