# table.ajax.reload() not triggering after success: function()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

**Intro**

I am doing a datatables.net jquery server-side processing using json, ajax, and php. I am able to click the row button and delete the row out of the database. However, the page never refreshes the page using ajax.reload();

**Project Link**
https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/

**Problem**

This code:

```
console.log("success function data reached");
```

seems to never be reached. What would cause that?

I have no errors and the table correctly deletes out of the database which is why I am stuck. Everything from datatables.net seems to be fine on their end, I most likely have a php problem?

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).on('click','.delete_btn',function (){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];
  var del_id = $('#example').DataTable().row( id ).data();
  var del_id = del_id[0];
  console.log(del_id[0]); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            dataType: 'json', //This says I'm expecting a response that is json encoded.
            cache: false,
            data: { 'del_id' : del_id}, 
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log("success function data reached");
              if(data=='result_ok'){  //You are checking for true/false 
                //document.location.reload(true);
               alert(data);
                table.ajax.reload();

              }else{
                console.log('The row was not deleted.');
                }
                }
        });
        });
</script>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
$del_id = $_POST['del_id']; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $del_id);
$confirmDelete = $stmt->execute();
//header("location: index.php");

if($confirmDelete){ //Check to see if there was an affected row.
 echo "result_ok";
}

echo json_encode($confirmDelete);
?>
```

Comment: I clearly didn't understand what do you want

Comment: Its free web hosting. You should purchase a quality service

Comment: Why are you using an array, normally you can do this way: if($confirmDelete){ echo "result_OK"
} 
and chech the returned value from ajax call: 
success: function(data){
if (data == 'result_OK') {
// do what you want
} else {
// do something on error
}
}

Comment: ok will try your way. that array method was from this persons answer here (which could be wrong) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923576/server-side-table-deletes-row-from-tables-but-not-database-using-js-php-or-a

Comment: try to see whats returning from ajax just alert data: success: function(data){ alert(data) }. data contains the result from the php script, no need to encode or use an array, also you can see the returned value using dev tools from the network tab by clicking on the php file

Comment: Do you want to check either php returns `true` or `false` in ajax return?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/image/rbwyfn93h/ You have errors on delete.php file

Comment: interesting. getting rid of session_start(): got rid of the session cookie errors.

Comment: this error:   Undefined index: del_id    is probably because you dont get the del_id info until you click a delete button. maybe i will  del_id = " "  to simplify the matters

Comment: changed the $array to confirmDelete. now it returns result_oktrue on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).on('click','.delete_btn',function (){
        var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];
        var del_id = $('#example').DataTable().row( id ).data();
        var del_id = del_id[0];
        //console.log(del_id[0]); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            data: {del_id:del_id}, 
            success: function(data){ 
                if (data=='DEL_OK') {
                  location.reload();
                } else {
                     alert('something wrong')
                  }
             })
        });
</script>
```

and the php code must be:

```
<?php
   $del_id = $_POST['del_id']; 
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?"); 
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $del_id);
   $confirmDelete = $stmt->execute();

   if($confirmDelete) {
      echo "DEL_OK";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah probably you have the connection message. On the screenshot i post for you, headers already send from file connection.php on line 9. Happy to help and feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your problem, you are not actually receiving the response from `php` in `ajax` correctly. `data` in ajax response is actually an array of characters.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'delete.php',
        data: {del_id:del_id}, 
        success: function(data){ 
            if (data[0]=='D') {//changing here
              location.reload();
            } else {
                 alert('something wrong')
              }
         })
    });
```

In php

```
<?php
  $del_id = $_POST['del_id']; 
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?"); 
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $del_id);
  $confirmDelete = $stmt->execute();

  if($confirmDelete) {
     echo "D";// echoing only D
  }
?>
```

Comment: Just noticed you have data[0], normally I’ve seen just plain data like the original answers . Interesting will have to alert to see what the difference is...

Comment: Yes. when you have multiple strings coming out then it is useful like you are echoing a string along with json